# How to use Tkinter input into a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to know how to get input from Tkinter and put it into a variable like a phone number or a piece of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
from tkinter import *


def get_variable_value():
    valueresult.set( strlname.get() + ' ' + strfname.get() ) #assign val variable to other
    print(valueresult.get()) #if you want see the result in the console


root = Tk()

strfname = StringVar()
strlname = StringVar()
valueresult = StringVar()

labelf = Label(root, text = 'First Name').pack()
fname = Entry(root, justify='left', textvariable = strfname).pack() #strlname get input 

labell = Label(root, text = 'Last Name').pack()
lname = Entry(root, justify='left', textvariable = strlname).pack() #strfname get input 

button = Button(root, text='Show', command=get_variable_value).pack()
res = Entry(root, justify='left', textvariable = valueresult).pack() #only to show result


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, can’t decode what is the meaning of: res = Entry(root, justify='left', textvariable = valueresult).pack() #only to show result ? Does this Entry widget show the result or is it getting the result ?

Comment: Wouldn’t res have a ‘state=DISABLED’ and a ‘ value result.set()’ option to be a read only Entry widget??

Answer (score 3):

```
from tkinter import *


def show_data():
    print( 'My First and Last Name are %s %s' % (fname.get(), lname.get()) )


win = Tk()
Label( win, text='First Name' ).grid( row=0 )
Label( win, text='Last Name' ).grid( row=1 )

fname = Entry( win )
lname = Entry( win )

fname.grid( row=0, column=1 )
lname.grid( row=1, column=1 )

Button( win, text='Exit', command=win.quit ).grid( row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4 )
Button( win, text='Show', command=show_data ).grid( row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4 )

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any code but you could try:

```
class GetPhoneNbr(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk.Tk()
        self.label = Tk.Label(self.root, text="Enter phone number")
        self.label.pack()

        self.phoneNbr = Tk.StringVar()   # <- here's what you need
        Tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.phoneNbr).pack()
```

NOTE:  This is a stub of code, not the entire class definition.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't add any code. The code i have right now is here:

Comment: import time
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = ""
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = ""

total_breaks = 2
break_count = 0

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

while(break_count < total_breaks):
    time.sleep(1)
    message = client.messages.create(
    to="number", 
    from_="number",
    body="Message")

    break_count = break_count + 1

    print(message.sid)
    print("Text sent")

Comment: but what i'm trying to do is make it so that what the user inputs in the window to be the body/message. The reason i asked this is because i'm new to Tk and python.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a minimal GUI that puts what's written in an entry to a variable, which is the button's text:

```
import tkinter as tk

def replace_btn_text():
    b['text'] = e.get()

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
b = tk.Button(root, text="Replace me!", command=replace_btn_text)

e.pack()
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Same example but with an OOP structure:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._create_widgets()
        self._display_widgets()

    def replace_btn_text(self):
        """ Replaces button's text with what's written in the entry.
        """
                                        # self._e.get() returns what's written in the
        self._b['text'] = self._e.get() # entry as a string, can be assigned to a var.

    def _create_widgets(self):
        self._e = tk.Entry(self)
        self._b = tk.Button(self, text="Replace me!", command=self.replace_btn_text)

    def _display_widgets(self):
        self._e.pack()
        self._b.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = App()
    root.mainloop()
```